# ScrollView - using scrollTo in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, android-scroll

I've got a scrollview that is on a Fragment that is on a ViewPager and I want to scroll it to some position on start, after `pager.setCurrentItem(numberOfPage);` where numberOfPage is a remembered last page.

So , if I do scrollTo() in a Fragment onCreateView() - it wouldn't scroll anywhere because it just creates view and not yet inflate it, so it doesn't scroll

I would of scroll it in a `onPageSelected(int position)` in Activity, but it works only on manually selected ViewPager's fragment and I'm setting it in the beginning as I already mentioned.

So, how can I scroll it right after Inflation?

Comment: Try calling the `scrollTo()` inside the Fragment's `onActivityCreated()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call scrollTo() method in Fragments [onViewCreated()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: it still doesn't scroll there

Comment: Thanx alot! onViewCreated() is what I needed!